# Substituting a for-loop with all permutations of an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

How is it possible to substitute a for-loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

which will go through the array like this: (1,2,...n) for something similar that will go through all permutations of the elements of the array. 
In other threads I have found this ([source](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/guava-collections2-utility-example/#permutations)):

```
public void permutations () {

    List<Integer> vals = Ints.asList(new int[] {1, 2, 3});

    Collection<List<Integer>> orderPerm = Collections2.permutations(vals);

    for (List<Integer> val : orderPerm) {
        logger.info(val);
    }

    assertEquals(6, orderPerm.size());
}
```

But I am unable to combine the two to make an "all permutations for-loop". Your help is greatly apprechiated. 
Just for clarification for an array of size 3 I want the loop to go through the array with the indices:

> [1, 2, 3] [1, 3, 2] [3, 1, 2] [3, 2, 1] [2, 3, 1] [2, 1, 3]

Comment: Why the solution you found in these other threads don't suit your needs ? The `Collections2.permutations(vals)` does exactly what you want.

Comment: It is safe to say that I'm still a beginner. To be honest the posted solution does look good, I just don't know how to actually use it. For example with myArray to aktually go through it in these orders. I would really appreciate it if you could maybe post an example of how I could do this! Thank you very much!

Comment: The `for (List<Integer> val : orderPerm)` line in your code seems to be exactly the example that you asked for. It goes through all permutations, one at a time. If you want something else, then please be more specific in your question.

Comment: Thank you fishinear, say I would want to print out the numbers, how could I do that? Or even better store it in a two dimensional field.

Comment: I can try to make an example for you, using your array and printing the numbers out. But, I don't understand how you could store them in a two dimensional field. What would be the two dimensions ?

Comment: An example would greatly help me. In the example from the post the first dimension could be {0,...,5} the number of combinations and the second {0,...,2} the number in each bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, as you asked :

```
// myArray with 1,2,3,...,n values
int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

// Convert it in a List to use it through guava Collections
List<Integer> vals = Ints.asList(myArray);  

// Compute all permutations using Guava Collections API
Collection<List<Integer>> orderPerm = Collections2.orderedPermutations(vals);

// Convert the result in List of Lists to get indexed values by number (to display them, easier to access than using an Iterator)
List<List<Integer>> myTwoDimensionalArray = new ArrayList<>(orderPerm);

// Loop over the result to display the 2 dimensional array
for (int dim1 = 0 ; dim1 < myTwoDimensionalArray.size() ; dim1++) {

  String dim2 = "";
  // Here I build a string to display the numbers without the brackets (not necessary)
  for (int i = 0 ; i < myTwoDimensionalArray.get(dim1).size() ; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      dim2 += ",";
    }
    dim2 += myTwoDimensionalArray.get(dim1).get(i);
  }

  // Displaying the 2 dimensional results
  System.out.println(dim1 + " : " + dim2);
  // Uncomment here to display with brackets directly
  // System.out.println(dim1 + " : " + myTwoDimensionalArray.get(dim1));
}
```

Just to be clear, here are the imports :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
```

It displays this output :

```
0 : 1,2,3
1 : 1,3,2
2 : 2,1,3
3 : 2,3,1
4 : 3,1,2
5 : 3,2,1
```

This one with brackets :

```
0 : [1, 2, 3]
1 : [1, 3, 2]
2 : [2, 1, 3]
3 : [2, 3, 1]
4 : [3, 1, 2]
5 : [3, 2, 1]
```

I've imported 2 jars in my project (using Maven) to use Guava collections :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>26.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
  <version>r03</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't know how to use Maven, just download these jars from the maven repository and copy them in your workspace to add them in your Java classpath.

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/26.0-jre
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-collections/r03

If your don't work in a workspace (like Eclipse), just compile your class using the javac `-classpath` option to add these jars in the compilation.

Here is a documentation about javac compilation : https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html

Answer (score 0):

For a more algorithmic solution. It will make copies of arrays, as "immutable" objects. A permutation array serves contains the *indexes* to be applied on the original array.

```
    int[] myArray = new int[] {10, 20, 30};
    int[] permutation = zeroPermutation(myArray.length);
    int n = 1 << myArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int[] arr = permute(myArray, permutation);
        System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", i, Arrays.toString(arr));
        permutation = nextPermutation(permutation);

    }
```

`zeroPermutation` delivers the array with indices 0, 1, 2, 3, ... - not permuting anything.

```
/**
 * An array 0, 1, 2, ...´, length-1.
 * <code>array[zeroPermutation(array.length)[i]] == array[i]</code>
 * @param length of array.
 * @return identity permutation.
 */
static int[] zeroPermutation(int length) {
    return IntStream.range(0, length).toArray();
}
```

The `nextPermutation` "counts upwards" taking the next "larger" sequence of indices.

```
static int[] nextPermutation(int[] permutation) {
    // Find the first position i from the right, that can made larger out of the right part.
    // ... [4] < 7 > 5 > 3 > 2 > 0
    //      i
    int i = permutation.length - 2;
    while (i >= 0 && permutation[i] > permutation[i + 1]) {
        --i;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        return zeroPermutation(permutation.length);
    }
    // Take the next larger:
    // ... [5] < 7 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 0
    //      \________/
    //      i        j
    int xi = permutation[i];
    int j = permutation.length - 1;
    while (j > i && xi > permutation[j]) {
        --j;
    }
    int[] next = Arrays.copyOf(permutation, permutation.length);
    next[i] = next[j];
    next[j] = xi;

    // And for the right part the smallest permutation:
    // By reversal of the order.
    // ... [5] < 0 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 7
    int nright = permutation.length - (i + 1);
    for (int k = 0; k < nright / 2; ++k) {
        int xk = next[i + 1 + k];
        next[i + 1 + k] = next[permutation.length - 1 - k];
        next[permutation.length - 1 - k] = xk;
    }
    return next;
}
```

And then we want to apply the permutation to an array, receiving the permutated array.

```
static int[] permute(int[] array, int[] permutation) {
    int[] permuted = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        permuted[i] = array[permutation[i]];
    }
    return permuted;
}
```

Some care is taken, that instead of copying one could change the arrays in-situ.