# Algorithm to get permutations of two arrays in java

Tags: java

Hello StackOverflow community !

I need this :

```
List<String> s1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"A0","B0","C0","D0"});
List<String> s2 = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"E0","F0","G0","H0"});
int iteration = 3;

List<String> result = permutations(s1,s2,iteration);

//result should contain : "A0E0B0F0C0G0", "A0E0B0F0D0H0",...
//result should not contain : some String begining with E0 in this example
//result should not have duplicate values

//Expected behaviour : 
//Pick one of the strings from s1, pick one of the strings from s2.
//Concatenate both. Repeat this process "iteration" times.
```

I found this : [Substituting a for-loop with all permutations of an array - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179886/substituting-a-for-loop-with-all-permutations-of-an-array-java)

It's useful but I don't know how to change it for my code.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

//Prints permutation of strings in 2 lists, first it takes string from first list and 
//then from second list, so on it repeats this process as the given "iteration" number of times
public class PermutationOfTwoArrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int iteration=3;
        List<String> s1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"A0","B0","C0","D0"});
        List<String> s2 = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"E0","F0","G0","H0"});
        int[] indexes=new int[2*iteration];
        printPermutationOfTwoArrays(iteration,s1,s2,0,indexes);
    }

    private static void printPermutationOfTwoArrays(int iteration, List<String> s1,
            List<String> s2,int currentIteration,int[] indexes)
    {
        if(currentIteration>=3) {
            System.out.println(s1.get(indexes[0])+s2.get(indexes[1])+
                    s1.get(indexes[2])+s2.get(indexes[3])+
                    s1.get(indexes[4])+s2.get(indexes[5]));
            return;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<s1.size();j++) {
            indexes[2*currentIteration]=j;
            for(int k=0;k<s2.size();k++) {
                indexes[2*currentIteration+1]=k;
                printPermutationOfTwoArrays(iteration, s1, s2, currentIteration+1, indexes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems perfect ! Well... as expected it's difficult to check the validity of your answer. I have some math to do to check it ;-)